# Apply function to specific selected columns in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, pandas-apply

I have the following dataframe:

```
# List of Tuples
matrix = [([22, 23], [34, 35, 65], [23, 29, 31]),
         ([33, 34], [31, 44], [11, 16, 18]),
         ([44, 56, 76], [16, 34, 76], [21, 34]),
         ([55, 34], [32, 35, 38], [22, 24, 26]),
         ([66, 65, 67], [33, 38, 39], [27, 32, 34]),
         ([77, 39, 45], [35, 36, 38], [11, 21, 34])]

# Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('xyz'), index=list('abcdef'))
```

[image]

I'm able to apply my custom function to output start, end items in list like below for all columns:

```
def fl(x):
    return [x[0], x[len(x)-1]]

df.apply(lambda x : [fl(i) for i in x])
```

[image]

But i want to apply the function to selected columns x & z.

I'm trying like below referring to this [link](https://thispointer.com/pandas-apply-a-function-to-single-or-selected-columns-or-rows-in-dataframe/)

```
df.apply(lambda x: fl(x) if x in ['x', 'y'] else x)
```

and like this:

```
df[['x', 'y']].apply(fl)
```

How to get the output with the function applied to only x and z columns with y column unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise processing, also for last value is possible use `[-1]` indexing:

```
def fl(x):
    return [x[0], x[-1]]

df[['x', 'z']] = df[['x', 'z']].applymap(fl) 
print (df)
          x             y         z
a  [22, 23]  [34, 35, 65]  [23, 31]
b  [33, 34]      [31, 44]  [11, 18]
c  [44, 76]  [16, 34, 76]  [21, 34]
d  [55, 34]  [32, 35, 38]  [22, 26]
e  [66, 67]  [33, 38, 39]  [27, 34]
f  [77, 45]  [35, 36, 38]  [11, 34]
```

Or for solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) use `zip` with mapping tuples to `list`s and selexting by `str`:

```
def fl(x):
    return list(map(list, zip(x.str[0], x.str[-1])))

df[['x', 'z']] = df[['x', 'z']].apply(fl) 
print (df)
          x             y         z
a  [22, 23]  [34, 35, 65]  [23, 31]
b  [33, 34]      [31, 44]  [11, 18]
c  [44, 76]  [16, 34, 76]  [21, 34]
d  [55, 34]  [32, 35, 38]  [22, 26]
e  [66, 67]  [33, 38, 39]  [27, 34]
f  [77, 45]  [35, 36, 38]  [11, 34]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make df.apply(lambda x: fl(x) if x in ['x', 'y'] else x) method work?

Comment: @sharathchandramandadi - Because `x` here is not column name, but Series like `df['x']`, `df['y']`

Answer (score 0):

Found out the mistake i'm doing.

Thanks for the reply.

I changed the function like below:

```
def fl(x):
    new = []
    for i in x:
        new.append([i[0], i[-1]])
    return new
```

Then applied the function like this.

```
df.apply(lambda x : fl(x) if x.name in ['x', 'z'] else x)
```

Then i'm able to get the expected output.